# Animate points and/or polygons on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, time, animation, torque

I am working with `leaflet`. I am wondering, if it is possible to animate points on the `leaflet` map like `cartoDB` is doing it with `torque.js`.
I basically need a timeslider for manual display and a play-button for automatic display of the data. I cannot use `torque.js` because my data depends on the user input and may change during a session various times. Uploading it to cartoDB is therefore no option. I am aware that there is the possibility to create `torque-tiles` from a `postGIS` database. But: loading the data which the user requests into a `postGIS` database, running the `.py` from `cartoDB` to create `torque-tiles` on it and then feeding it to the `torque framework` sounds hacky.

I am further interested in applying the solution - if possible - to polygons. I need to change a choropleth map over time.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using d3js.

This example seems to match what you want : http://stat4701-edav-d3.github.io/viz/cities/cities.html

Comment: Yes, I am working with `d3.js`. Is there the commented code somewhere? It looks like what I need...

Comment: The (non-commented..) code is available here : view-source:http://stat4701-edav-d3.github.io/viz/cities/js/main.js. I am working on an adaptation of this script and the code is not too hard to get in especially if you already work with d3js. You basically need to use and adapt the createSlider,() animate() and drawMonth() functions.

Comment: Thanks. I found the sourcecode already. I thought there might be a commented version that I overlooked. I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Check this  [guide](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/)
Is a guide of how to animate a path in map using d3